# Accidentally insulting the prophet

Tags: salat, prophets, waswasa

I feel terrible, today when I prayed ( in the final tasshahud) I accidentally insulted the prophet , I ask forgiveness from Allah and then I’ve retaken them prayer , does this count as a sin that Allah won’t forgive?

Comment: How did you end up insulting the Prophet during Tashahud? Genuinely curious.

Comment: @Ten I think it's ok that the asker does not want to repeat what he has said.

Comment: No, it is not okay brother. Astaghfirullah!!!!!!!!!! @Jeschu

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a scholar, so take what I say with a grain of salt.

In general, according to Islam, actions are judged according to the intentions.

> On the authority of Ameer ul-Mu’mineen (the Commander of the
> Faithful), Abu Hafs `Umar ibn al-Khattab radiAllahu anhu, who said: I
> heard the Messenger of Allah sallAllahu alayhi wa sallam say:
>
> “Actions are but by intentions and every man shall have only that
> which he intended. Thus he whose migration (Hijrah to Madeenah from
> Makkah) was for Allah and His Messenger, his migration was for Allah
> and His Messenger, and he whose migration was to achieve some worldly
> benefit or to take some woman in marriage, his migration was for that
> for which he migrated."
>
> [Reported in Bukhari and Muslim](https://hadithcommentary.com/nawawi/hadith1/)

So if for example you "insulted" the Prophet (pbuh) by mispronouncing an Arabic word, you didn't really sin because it was not your intention to insult him in the first place. This was simply a mistake.

Answer (score -2):

If someone commits such an ugly act as an accident or a joke, he has sinned and must repent.

Comment: but brother the repent might not be accepted since prophet Muhammad Sallah Allah Alayhee wa Salam is dead. Therefore, repentance must not be accepted and the hudud must be applied.

Comment: @Kamola Leave the judgement to Whom it belongs, and think about the meaning of the Sura we recite 5 times a day.

Comment: @Jeschu which sura do you recite 5 times a day?

Comment: @Jamila I mean that He is the most merciful and ruler over the Final Judgement. How should we judge without mercy and in His Name?

Answer (score -3):

I think the punishment for insulting the prophet Salla allah alayhe wa salam, even if by accident is to be put to the sword. I don't know but theres no second chance.

Comment: What you think doesn't matter, we are looking for well explained answers including evidences supporting your claims.

Comment: Many uluma have stated that the punishment for insulting the prophet Salla allah alayhe wa salam is to be punished with a strike of a sword @Medi1Saif

Comment: You didn't share sny evidence for that.

Comment: In your answer you said "I don't know", can that be considered as a good answer??